# How to restrict file extensions in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-team-site

I'm using SharePointOnline's Modern UI.

I would like to display an error message if a user uploads anything other than a PDF file in the document library.
Is there any way to achieve this other than an event receiver?

I would appreciate any ideas or pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, there is no OOB approach to block certain file types in a library, Here is a [User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/12498615-custom-restrictions-of-file-types-that-user-can-up) where you can vote for adding this feature.